# Error exporting rep checkout in script

Tags: macos, bash, svn

I get this error when trying to export a rep checkout to a folder using a bash script:

```
svn: E125001: Couldn't determine absolute path of '.'
svn: E000002: No such file or directory
```

Performing the same export command in Terminal works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found out the problem... the bash script used a loop to export and build trunk and tags from repositories. Long story short, **in the script, I needed to cd into a valid working dir before doing a SVN export**. The SVN client was updated yesterday after installing a new XCode (I think...) and I guess making sure there is valid working dir is a good thing.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem by running the `svn look` command in a terminal whose current directory **did not exist anymore**.

The same error message in french:

```
> svn: E125001: Impossible de déterminer le chemin absolu de '.' 
> svn: E000002: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
```

I just had to `cd` to an existing directory before trying again.

Answer (score 1):

it seems you deleted the directory
so check if the directory exists 
to solve it

```
cd ..
mkdir <your_direvtory_again> 
cd <your_direvtory_again>
```